# UICollectionView not populating from Array with data

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have an array of 115 objects containing name and photo url string from Firebase. Printing the data shows results so i know its pulling data correctly.

The problem is the Cells are never populated by the data.

If i add a print(name) inside the class DJProfileCell: UICollectionViewCell it never gets called so i believe thats where the issue is.

```
         class VLCDJProfileViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

            @IBOutlet weak var similarArtistsCollection: UICollectionView!

            var ref: DatabaseReference!
            let profileCellID = "cellId"
            var djObject = SimilarDJ(image: "image1", name: "name1")
            var djsSimilarArray = [SimilarDJ]()


        override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
                ref = Database.database().reference()
                loadDJs()

                collectionView?.register(DJProfileCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: profileCellID)

            }

        func loadDJs(){

                let allDJs = self.ref.child("DJ")

                allDJs.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                    for child in snapshot.children {
                        let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                        let djsDict = snap.value as! [String: Any]
                        let PhotoUrl = djsDict["PhotoUrl"] as! String
                        let name = djsDict["name"] as! String + "    "


                        self.djObject = SimilarDJ   (image: PhotoUrl, name: name + "   ")
                        self.djsSimilarArray.append(self.djObject)


                        self.similarArtistsCollection.reloadData();


                    }
                })
            }

        override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return djsSimilarArray.count
        }

        override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: profileCellID, for: indexPath) as! DJProfileCell

            cell.djprofile = djsSimilarArray[indexPath.item]

            return cell
        }

    class DJProfileCell: UICollectionViewCell {


        var djprofile: SimilarDJ?  {
            didSet {

                guard let djImageProfile = djprofile?.image else {return}
                guard let djNameProfile = djprofile?.name else {return}

                let url = URL(string: djImageProfile)
                djImageView.kf.indicatorType = .activity
                djImageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
                djImageLabel.text = djNameProfile
                djImageLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true


            }
        }

        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
setup()

        }

func setup(){


    self.backgroundColor = .white
    self.addSubview(djImageView)
    self.addSubview(djImageLabel)

    }



        let djImageView: UIImageView = {

            let iv = UIImageView()
        //    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        //    iv.backgroundColor = .green
            return iv

        }()

        let djImageLabel: MarqueeLabel = {

            let label = MarqueeLabel()
            label.text = "Name"
            label.textColor = UIColor.black
            label.font = label.font.withSize(14)

            label.textAlignment = .center

            return label

        }()



        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init has not been implemented")
        }

    }

    struct SimilarDJ {

        let image: String?
        let name: String?


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in cell class - djImageView and djImageLabel are never added to the view's hierarchy. I see no IBOutlet and no addSubview().

Comment: Ive added that code and the IBOoutlet is hooked up but still no results. It never calls the Cell function byt prints out firebase results. Its possibly this line of code collectionView?.register(DJProfileCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: profileCellID)

Comment: is setup() getting called in the cell class?
inside a cell you better add inner views to '.contentView' property.
I would recommend that you download and play a bit with an example collection view project since your code contains several problems.
design the cell in its own xib, make sure the collection has the right constraints etc.

Comment: I have several uicollection views already in app but this doesn't work for some reason. Only difference is it uses storyboard instead of being programmatic. The cell function is never called so the setup function isn't either.